# Uploading file from android okhttp to codeigniter

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, file-upload, okhttp

As described in the question above, I'm trying to upload a file from okhttp3 to the server.

I'm always receiving 'You did not select a file to upload' in my approach from codeIgniter part.

Here's my code

**Android**:

```
    public void sendItem(File item) {
        Response response = null;
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse(FileUtils.getMimeType(item));
        try {
            RequestBody formBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().addFormDataPart("item", item.getName(), RequestBody.create(mediaType, item)).build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder().url("index.php").post(formBody).build();

            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            int statusCode = response.code(); // always 500

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (response != null)
                response.close();
        }
    }
```

**Server Code:**

```
    function upload(){
        $config['upload_path'] = '.../assets/...';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        $media = 'item';
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($media)) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            print_r($error);
        }else{
            $stuff = $this->upload->data();
            return $stuff ;
        }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you have in `$media` ?

Comment: codeigniter upload library works only on php version 5.6 and above so make sure that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that CodeIgniter requires you to set the `$config['allowed_types']` as part of the library initialization.  The default installation doesn't set 'allowed types' so you must explicitly set it in your controller or in a config file per the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#setting-preferences).

You need to add something like `$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';` before you initialize your library.

That said, this might not be your only issue.

Comment: allowed_types is not mandatory, it can be placed if you'd like to limit to certain extensions.

Comment: Disagree.  You can create a global config file for file uploads and set $config['allowed_types'] = "*";  Or you can set it in the controller before initialization.  If you don't set it at all, the library will refuse to work.  The documentation for this library is pretty bad.

Comment: I totally missed the global config part, you're correct here @Wade

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a `print_r($_FILES);` in your server code & see if the file data is being sent in that variable?

The message of 'You did not select a file to upload' is shown from CodeIgniter's Upload library only when no file has been sent in $_FILES.

And you should also try echoing `print_r($_POST);` to ascertain if your file data is coming in $_POST or in $_FILES.

Comment: that's not an answer at all.

Comment: Sure, that might not be the answer. But the do_upload() of CodeIgniter upload library looks in the $_FILES array for the 'item' variable, so it will look for $_FILES['item'] element. Unless you are getting that, this message is going to come.